# laravel не удается подключить IndexController?

Tags: laravel, controller

Всем привет. Не удается подключить IndexController, что делать? Всегда так делал, а тут ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В новой ларе нет дефолтного неймспейса, объявляйте уже в новом стиле, или укажите дефолтный неймспейс в провайдере

Comment: да заглянул в новую ДОК. убрали злодеи)) Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В новой ларе нет дефолтного неймспейса, объявляйте уже в новом стиле, или укажите дефолтный